# Unfreeze Page header in Excel

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I insert page header for the report and found that it will always freeze in the excel. I just want the page header can always show in each page of PDF but not freeze in Excel. I don't want the header always pin in top when I am scrolling.

Is there any property can select to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you checked in the SSRS report if that header / row has a `FixedData` property set to True? Or maybe check in the properties of the header to see if the `Header should remain visible while scrolling` is ticked.

Comment: I am talking about the page header, not table header. I checked the properties panel. But it seem that page header do not have these properties.

Comment: Page Headers are rather weird because they are separate from the main rdl so there isn't any options specifically for it to stop freezing and stuff. I would usually not use Page Header and create the Header from my table or use something else that allows me to control if it can be fixed for scrolling or to have it repeat on all pages.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to repeat page header in each page without fixing it, you could add a textbox in report, then set "Repeat With"  corresponding Tablix(which each group one page).

Or insert a List, insert a textbox(with corresponding text) in List, set List group properties with corresponding Group and set page break between each instance.

Or you could set this in Excel, View->Freeze Pane->Unfreeze